# OpenLayers basic Vector Math operation: add, subtract, normalize

Tags: openlayers, vector, jsts

Is there a supported or built-in way to do basic Vector2D Math operation in OpenLayers v6 ?

Currently using p5.Vector library (from p5js.org) to do add, subtract, normalize.
JSTS does not export Vector2D.Math library, so cannot use JSTS.

Comment: There are no such functions for Cartesian vector mathematics in OL.